# Update Database automatically at specific time

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, scheduled-tasks

I have one issue, but I'm not getting a solution. I tried Google too.

I want to update my SQL database on the first day of every month (i.e. 01/01/2012, 01/02/2012, 01/03/2012, etc.)  I am using C# (code behind language) and ASP.NET.  I do not want any human effort for this. I want this update to be done automatically, on a specific date. Is there any kind of solution that can solve my problem?

If I am not clear about my doubt then let me know.

Comment: What kind of update? You can use Windows Task Scheduler to run specific tasks at specific times for instance.

Comment: You should not use ASP.NET for this since it would only be active if at least one user is logged in. Instead you should use a `WindowsService`, a `Task-Scheduler` that triggers a program or [SSIS Schedules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd440761(v=sql.100).aspx) for this.

Comment: Hey Tim Schmelter... thanx man ..... thanx for the idea. I have now created the service for my task to be established and its working great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to the `SQL Server Job Agent`, I would create a stored procedure that contains the `UPDATE` code and then use a Job to run the stored proc each month on the first day of the month.

Your steps would be:

1. Create stored procedure with your `UPDATE`
2. Create a new SQL Agent Job that executes your stored proc
3. When setting the schedule on the SQL Agent Job, set it as recurring > Monthly > The first day of every 1 month.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Why not create an application that does the update you require, and then set up a schedule to run it with the Windows Task Scheduler?

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET is not the best option for a scheduled task. A simple console app scheduled with [Windows Task Scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

you have to create a script or an application that updates your database, and schedule it in the task scheduler if your are using Windows...